# Componente para formatação de texto em HTML

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu estou a procura de um componente onde o usuário possa digitar o texto desejado e fazer a formatação do texto como bem entender.

Algo parecido com esse do **SO** ou da imagem abaixo.
[image]

Alguém conhece algum?

Obs: Estou usando C# (Winforms)

Comment: Eu uso este http://www.sceditor.com/, pra mim o mais simples e o melhor.

Comment: O problema é que o projeto é windows forms. De qualquer forma eu vou salvar o link, parece ser muito bom @Marconi

Comment: Hum, foi mal cara, esqueçi que não é web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sei que esta pergunta é antiga, mas talvez o link abaixo ajude à alguem:

[TX Text Control .NET Express](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0fae82e8-7679-4977-8c72-41da543c31d4)

Comment: Foi a solução que eu achei melhor, por isso marquei como correta. Obrigado pela contribuição.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esse componente possa lhe ajudar:

https://www.componentsource.com/product/aspose-email-for-net

e também tem esse editor html para windows form:

http://www.modeltext.com/html/

Comment: porém pra essa questão acho desnecessário a postagem do código, pois são componentes prontos que devem ser baixados diretamente do site.